# Cant get UIButton to highlight with TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I've setup a tap gesture recognizer and add the recognizer to the uibutton. The button has a background image. When I tap the button it doesn't highlight at all, the only thing I've been able to get it to do is change it's alpha value.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
     singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [btnNext addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
UIView *tappedView = [gesture.view hitTest:[gesture locationInView:gesture.view] withEvent:nil];
NSLog(@"Touch event view: %@",[tappedView class]);
UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *) tappedView;
[self highlightButton:myButton];
tappedView.alpha = 0.5f;

}
```

Any would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept the touches events with a gesture recognizer, and then programmatically add the recognizer to all your uibuttons. For instance:

```
//
//  HighlighterGestureRecognizer.h
//  Copyright 2011 PathwaySP. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface HighlightGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer {
    id *beganButton;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id *beganButton;

@end
and the implementation:

//
//  HighlightGestureRecognizer.m
//  Copyright 2011 PathwaySP. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HighlightGestureRecognizer.h"


@implementation HighlightGestureRecognizer

@synthesize beganButton;

-(id) init{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.beganButton = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] view];
    if ([beganButton isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]]) {
        [beganButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey_screen"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self performSelector:@selector(resetImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)reset
{
}

- (void)ignoreTouch:(UITouch *)touch forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (BOOL)canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventingGestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)canPreventGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventedGestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}

- (void)resetImage
{
    [beganButton setBackgroundImage: nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

@end
```

The way you'd add the gesture recognizer to your button would be like so:

```
HighlighterGestureRecognizer * tapHighlighter = [[HighlighterGestureRecognizer alloc] init];

[myButton addGestureRecognizer:tapHighlighter];
[tapHighlighter release];
```

So basically you're declaring it, initializing it, and then adding it. After that, you'll want to release it, since the addGestureRecognizer retains it.

Also simply try

`adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES` set on your buttons? The default is YES, but maybe you changed it in the xib. It's the "Highlighted Adjusts Image" checkbox in the attributes inspector:

[image]